# is there a dataset of financial blogs?

Tags: data-request, metadata, social-media, media

I am looking for a database that contains the name of all the `financial blogs` out there.

Ideally each blog should be linked to the website it refers to (say, I need to be able to know that blog X is a blog from the financial Times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to this question are easily found with a search engine. For example,

A list of 789 financial blogs:

**[Top Personal Finance Blogs](http://www.wisebread.com/top-100-most-popular-personal-finance-blogs)**

There is no export, but the 7 pages of HTML-tables are pretty readable

```
<tr class="odd">
   <td class="col-counter">601</td>
   <td class="col-counter "></td>
   <td class="text col-name"><a href="/top-100-most-popular-personal-finance-blogs/borrow-from-none" title="View profile and stats for Borrow From None">Borrow From None</a></td>
   <td class="text col-name"><a href="http://www.borrowfromnone.com/" title="Visit Borrow From None" target="_blank"><img src="/top-100-most-popular-personal-finance-blogs/sites/wisebread.com.top-100-most-popular-personal-finance-blogs/themes/custom/ixbl/fugue-icons/icons/external.png" class="site-link-icon" /></a></td>
   <td class="col-twitter text"><a href="http://twitter.com/bfnJohn" class="twitter-link" target="_blank" title="Go to Borrow From None&#039;s Twitter page">bfnJohn</a></td>
   <td class="number">26.43</td>
   <td class="number">4.18</td>
   <td class="number">606</td>
   <td class="number">10.14</td>
   <td class="number">423</td>
   <td class="number">3,760,824</td>
   <td class="number">-</td>
</tr>
```

And the corresponding view in the browser

[image]

Here's an online tool to [convert HTML tables to CSV](http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm). There will be many others, although doing it yourself programmatically is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another list that's updated more frequently and has slightly different metrics, should also be easy to parse (minus the pagination):

http://www.investmentzen.com/top-personal-finance-blogs